# Java Streams extract strings starting with "EXCHANGEID="

Tags: java, string, parsing, lambda, java-stream

I have the following file:

> 1. |IRIS.CLIENTID=CONTRALI_C|IRIS.**EXCHANGEID=XPAR**|ISINCODE=FR0011898584|
> 2. IRIS.**EXCHANGEID=NYSE**|ISINCODE=FR0011898584|
> 3. _C|IRIS.**EXCHANGEID=ALXP**|ISINCODE=FR0011898584

that has multiple lines (I've only extracted a minor section).
I want to extract each string starting with "EXCHANGEID=" using Java Streams and print it on the console.

So I want my output to be like:

XPAR NYSE ALXP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if the elements you wish to print have a fixed length (they seem to have length 4 in your example), you can write:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
     .map(s->{
              int index = s.indexOf("EXCHANGEID=");
              return index>=0?s.substring(index+11,index+15):null;
         })
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great!